# Numeric values in ComboBox

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a combo box `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` control filled with numeric values.  I'd like for the user to be able to type multiple characters to set the value but this only works if I specify the `CBS_SORT` flag which sorts the value 10 before 2.

Is there a way I can get typing working correctly while keeping my values sorted numerically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a related question where posted some C-code to handle this. Maybe it helps:

[Jump to listbox item by typing first few characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308809/jump-to-listbox-item-by-typing-first-few-characters/1311039#1311039)

Comment: If I need to roll my own this looks like it will help.  Still hoping I'm missing something and I only need to set a flag!

Comment: Thanks - I ended up rolling my own using the code you linked as a reference.  Really wasn't as bad as I expected.  The only piece I skipped was the just about invisible caret that I suspect few folks have even noticed.